# How to calculate RoM spine using two nodes

Tags: matlab, nodes, angle, abaqus, motion

I want to calculate the range of motion (ROM) of my spine simulation in Abaqus. I created two nodes of which I use the coordinates (y,z);

[image]

In the figure you see the initial model (green) and the blue model. I want to calculate the RoM by measuring the angle difference between the two lines (line AB and line CD). I know the initial coordinates (y,z since the motion is in zy plane) and the coordinates after simulation. I used the formulas of this website because the lines do not share a common starting point: https://www.redcrab-software.com/en/Calculator/Angles-Of-Lines
I try to calculate the RoM using the following code in Matlab;

```
% Flexion
% A coordinates
a_y = -1.2957500E+02;
a_z = -4.6569600E+02;

b_y = -1.32482e+02;
b_z = -4.69579e+02;

% B coordinates (scaled)
c_y =  -1.64725e+02;
c_z = -4.72290e+02;

d_y = -1.66319e+02;
d_z = -4.77098e+02;

%% Move lines to one starting point
a = [a_y; a_z]
b = [b_y; b_z]

c = [c_y; c_z]
d = [d_y; d_z]


lineAB = a - b
lineCD = c - d

% Magnitude
ABCD = (lineAB(1) * lineCD(1)) + (lineAB(2) * lineCD(2));

% Absolute value
AB = sqrt((lineAB(1)^2)+(lineAB(2)^2))
CD = sqrt((lineCD(1)^2)+(lineCD(2)^2))

Cosalpha = ABCD/(AB*CD)
Alpha_rad = acos(Cosalpha)
% Alpha_deg = Alpha_rad/pi*180
Alpha_deg = rad2deg(Alpha_rad)
```

But the angles for extension 87 degrees is and for flexion is 18 degrees according to my code.
When measuring by hand (figure), it is so different. What am I not seeing here? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure about your coordinates? The calculations (Although a bit messy) are correct

Comment: Your coordinates are incorrect for sure (Also, the angle in your "flexion" case is not 23 degrees on your image, it is 19). Getting approx. coordinates from your image gives angles of 19 and 35 degree